# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File and path verified?

Tags: python-3.x

This is the print out in Python 3.5.1 Shell:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\victoria\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32'

>>> import os

>>> os.path.abspath('.\\hello')
'C:\\Users\\victoria\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\hello'

>>> helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\victoria\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\python\\Python35-32\\hello.txt')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    helloFile = open('C:\\Users\\victoria\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\python\\Python35-32\\hello.txt')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\victoria\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\python\\Python35-32\\hello.txt'
```

What am I reading wrong?  I have the .txt file "hello" and it's path verified.

Comment: `hello` and `hello.txt` are two different files. Are you sure yours is called `hello.txt`? If it is, another difference is that your actual path contains `\Python\ ` with an uppercase `P`, while you try to open a path with `\python\ ` with a lowercase `p`. Shouldn't matter on Windows as far as I know, but worth a shot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to open a file that don't exist or you don't put the right name for it. Perhaps you file is actually called `hello` but when you try to open it you call it as `hello.txt` which don't exist

Also [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) don't give you the path to a actual file, it convert a given path into absolute version of it

To check the existence of a file, you must use [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)

example

```
>>> import os
>>> path=os.path.abspath(".\\fake_file.txt")
>>> path
'C:\\Users\\David\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\fake_file.txt'
>>> os.path.exists(path)
False
>>> path2=os.path.abspath(".\\test.txt")
>>> path2
'C:\\Users\\David\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\test.txt'
>>> os.path.exists(path2)
True
>>>
```